# Android: Videoview media controller keys are not shown as focused when using D-pad

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-hardware-keyboard

I am using a videoview to play videos in full screen. I have a hardware keyboard connected to my Android device. 
Now when I press 'enter' key  while a video is being played in full screen, I get a media
controls at the bottom.
By default, the focus is on 'play/pause' button, pressing left/right keys on the D-pad takes the focus to seekforward/seekbackward respectively.
Everything is working fine, the only problem is, the media controllers are not visible as focused. Is is possible to achieve this? or do I need to  write my own custom controls??

Comment: Can you explain "the media controllers are not visible as focused"? You mean next and previous?

Comment: @Dave The focus shifts to play/rewind/forward keys on using the D-pad. But the thing is you cannot actually see on which key the focus is right now.

Comment: Did you find any solution?? @Code_Yoga